# Stars left to theorem (for exercises)

Tags: amsthm

I would like to be able to do something like this

`\begin{exo}[Name][\Star\Star] 
Content 
\end{exo}`

which would print something like

```
**Exercise 7 (Name). Content
```

I want exo's counter to share the counter with other theorems and be able to reference it with cref. If possible, I would like to use amsthm to minimize the changes in my files.

An example of code that I would like to work

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{amsthm}

\begin{document}
\newtheorem{eDef}{Def}
\newtheorem{eExo}[eDef]{Exo}

\begin{eDef}[Name]
Content
\end{eDef}

\begin{eExo}[Name][**]
Content
\end{eExo}

\begin{eExo}[Name][*]
Content
\end{eExo}

\begin{eExo}[Name][***]
Content
\end{eExo}
\end{document}
```

Resulting in

```
Def 1 (Name). Content
**Exercise 2 (Name). Content
*Exercise 3 (Name). Content
***Exercise 4 (Name). Content
```

Comment: `\newtheorem{eExo}[eDef]{**Exercise}` is sufficent?

Comment: No because some exercise would have two stars, other one or three stars. I'm not sure creating an environment for each difficulty is the right solution. Unless it is?

Comment: @x4rkz I'm not sure why the exercises don't have their own counter. The number of asterisks indicates the difficulty; you can use the `Exercise` package.

Comment: You're right, I don't think I need them to use the same counter. I didn't know this pacakge, gonna learn about it

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The main problem is the double optional argument. I suggest using a different syntax in order to distinguish between them.

```latex
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsthm,xparse}

\theoremstyle{definition}
\newtheorem{eDef}{Def}
\newtheorem{eExoinner}[eDef]{\Exoname}
\newcommand{\Exoname}{Exo}

\NewDocumentEnvironment{eExo}{D(){}o}
 {\renewcommand\Exoname{\makebox[0pt][r]{#1}Exo}%
  \IfNoValueTF{#2}{\eExoinner}{\eExoinner[#2]}}
 {\endeExoinner}

\begin{document}

\begin{eDef}[Name]
Content
\end{eDef}

\begin{eExo}[Name]
Content
\end{eExo}

\begin{eExo}(*)[Name]
Content
\end{eExo}

\begin{eExo}(**)[Name]
Content
\end{eExo}

\begin{eExo}(***)[Name]
Content
\end{eExo}

\begin{eExo}
Content
\end{eExo}

\begin{eExo}(*)
Content
\end{eExo}

\begin{eExo}(**)
Content
\end{eExo}

\begin{eExo}(***)
Content
\end{eExo}

\end{document}
```

[image]

A different strategy is to define four different environments.

```latex
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsthm}

\theoremstyle{definition}
\newtheorem{eDef}{Def}
\newtheorem{eExoinner}[eDef]{\makebox[0pt][r]{\Exostar}Exo}
\newcommand{\Exostar}{}

\newenvironment{eExo}{\eExoinner}{\endeExoinner}
\newenvironment{eExo*}{\renewcommand\Exostar{*}\eExoinner}{\endeExoinner}
\newenvironment{eExo**}{\renewcommand\Exostar{**}\eExoinner}{\endeExoinner}
\newenvironment{eExo***}{\renewcommand\Exostar{***}\eExoinner}{\endeExoinner}

\begin{document}

\begin{eDef}[Name]
Content
\end{eDef}

\begin{eExo}[Name]
Content
\end{eExo}

\begin{eExo*}[Name]
Content
\end{eExo*}

\begin{eExo**}[Name]
Content
\end{eExo**}

\begin{eExo***}[Name]
Content
\end{eExo***}

\begin{eExo}
Content
\end{eExo}

\begin{eExo*}
Content
\end{eExo*}

\begin{eExo**}
Content
\end{eExo**}

\begin{eExo***}
Content
\end{eExo***}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Your first suggestion is superb...

Comment: @MadyYuvi I absolutely agree with you :-)